# excel increment cell containing time in hour and minute format using active x controls

Tags: excel, vba, time

I hope someone can please help with this, i have an excel spreadsheet where i have the following time displayed in my cell A1.

Cell A1

```
00:00
```

the first set of 00 is my hours the second set of 00 is my minutes.

Next to this cell i have two sets of Active X Controls which are up/down arrows

```
Cell A1   ^ ^
          V V
```

When a user clicks the arrows i want the time to increment, so if they click up on the first set of arrows this will increment the time to 01, 02, 03 etc as my hours all the way to 23 hours and then back to 00 hours representing 12 o clock midnight.

If the user clicks the down arrow this should de-increment the numbers, i.e. if the time is 03:00 and the user clicks the down arrow, this should go down like, `02, 01, 00 hours.`

The next set of active x control arrows should control the minutes, like so :

01-59 and when the minutes go to 60 this should increment the hour up by 1.

so something like this:

```
22:59  ^ ^  <--- If user hits the up arrow for the minutes this then shows:

23:00
```

could someone please show me how i could create a vba code that would do what i need. many thanks

Comment: A lot of info in here : http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/spin-button.html

Answer (score 1):

it is very simple just do this

for up arrow

```
Hours -> range("A1").value = DateAdd("h", 1, range("A1").value)
Minutes -> range("A1").value = DateAdd("m", 1, range("A1").value)
Seconds -> range("A1").value = DateAdd("s", 1, range("A1").value)
```

for down arrow

```
Hours -> range("A1").value = DateAdd("h", -1, range("A1").value)
Minutes -> range("A1").value = DateAdd("m", -1, range("A1").value)
Seconds  -> ("A1").value = DateAdd("s", -1, range("A1").value)
```